# Get the nearest location to user from Json

Tags: android, json, location

I'm new to Android, I'm creating an app to get the nearest geocaches to the device's current location..

I have this bit of code :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap map;
TextView test;
private ArrayList<LatLng> markers = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

// main code.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

    String result = JSON
            .getResult("http://www.student.soc.napier.ac.uk/~40053830/CMS/markers.php");

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int j = 0; j < jArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
            LatLng tmp = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(json_data
                    .getString("latitude")), Double.parseDouble(json_data
                    .getString("longitude")));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(tmp).title(
                    json_data.getString("name")));
            markers.add(tmp);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    Location myLocation = map.getMyLocation();
    Location nearest = new Location("nearest");
    nearest.setLatitude(markers.get(0).latitude);
    nearest.setLongitude(markers.get(0).longitude);
    float distance = myLocation.distanceTo(nearest);
    for (int i = 1; i < markers.size(); i++) {
        Location target = new Location("target");
        target.setLatitude(markers.get(i).latitude);
        target.setLongitude(markers.get(i).longitude);

        if (myLocation.distanceTo(target) < distance) {
            nearest = target;
            distance = myLocation.distanceTo(target);
        }
    }
    test.setText((String.format("%.02f", distance * 0.000621371192)));
}
```

I can't seem to get the distance to the nearest on the textview..

here's the logcat :

```
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421): Process:         com.finlaysmith.MotorcycleParking, PID: 16421
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.finlaysmith.MotorcycleParking/com.finlaysmith.MotorcycleParking.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at com.finlaysmith.MotorcycleParking.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-18 19:01:50.463: E/AndroidRuntime(16421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

I know it's the " Float distance.. but I can't find how to resolve it..

Thanks

Comment: why are you using strictmode?

Comment: What is line 66 in `MainActivity.java`?. `getMap()` could also return null. Better Check the availability of google play services before initializing map object. Also it seems you are doing net operation and i hope you are using a thread or asynctask for that

Answer (score 1):

map.myLocation is returning null because it hasn't found your location yet.  That may take some time.  You need to check for null and not do this part of the code if the return is null (you can do it later, once it has your location).

Comment: When I use a button to get the nearest location, my code works, but when i want it to show when i open the app it's not working..

Comment: Because you don't have a location yet.  It takes time for the app to figure it out, it isn't ready in onCreate.

Comment: So, how should it do it ?